# How could I reduce the time complexity of this nested loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm in the process of learning to optimize code and implement more data structures and algorithms in my programs, however I'm experiencing difficulties with this code block.

My primary goal is to reduce this from a O(n**2) time complexity mainly not using a nested loop.

```
numArray = np.array([[20, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4], [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]], dtype=int)
rolls = [[] for i in range(len(numArray[0]))]

for i in range(len(numArray[0])):
    for j in range(numArray[1, i]):
        rolls[i].append(random.randint(1, numArray[0, i]))
```

The code is supposed to generate x amount of random integers (where x is index i of the second numArray subarray, e.g. 10) between 1 and index i of the first numArray subarray (e.g. 20).

Then repeat this for each index in the first numArray subarray.
(In the whole dice program numArray subarrays are user generated integers, but I assigned fixed numbers to it for simplicities sake while optimizing.)

Comment: Can you provide how the desired output and shape should look like. (Maybe shrink it down even more for here)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.random.randint` since you're already importing `numpy`. It accepts a *size* argument to produce multiple random values in one go.

```
rolls = [list(np.random.randint(1, numArray[0][idx], val)) for idx, val in enumerate(numArray[1])]
```

This of course assumes that both lists in `numArray` are the same length, but should get you somewhere at least.